# How to get a Linux panic output to a USB serial console when system has also a display adapter

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, serial-port, usb, panic

I am having troubles with a Linux kernel panic which I need to investigate further. When it happens, the kernel panic output always goes to the display adapter only and is shown on the monitor.
I need to have the kernel panic output to a serial USB console, not only on the display adapter. In the situation where the panic happens there is no monitor available.

I have a serial USB console working, can log in from there and I also see some kernel messages there sometimes. However when I provoke a kernel panic with `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`the kernel panic output is just on the display adapter visible, not on USB console.

I am using Debian 8 with kernel 4.14. ttyUSB0 is running with systemd.
Kernel cmdline contains ... `console=tty0 console=ttyUSB0,9600n8`

What I can do to get the kernel panic logged to USB serial port?

Comment: USB Serial device can't be used as kernel console. Though, you may either use USB debug mode (needs a highly priced equipment in case of USB 2.0) or use USB 3.0 capability with special cable (for example Intel xHCI supports it). Read my earlier answer on the matter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511533/can-i-get-debug-information-on-usb/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you only need access to the kernel dump information *somehow*, without having a monitor attached. You can set up kdump to automatically save a kernel dump image to disk which you can then later have look at. Here's a tutorial on how to setup this on Debian: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/oops-debugging-kernel-panics-0

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible in Linux to dump any message after kernel panic on USB console. You may try to configure ethernet console but in this case I also doubt if it will dump anything during panic. If I'm not wrong you will be successful only with serial UART console.

Comment: Not exactly. See my comment to OP.